# Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the below scripts to create Charts in asp.net MVC but i am getting an error saying 
"Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined in Highcharts.js" 
"Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of undefined in exporting.js"

The scripts that are added are :

```
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AmitSoni updated it

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">` should be inserted before any other `js`.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao its giving an error with highcharts..
 Highcharts is not defined in exporting.js

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks and i tried it  but gave me  error in exporting.js -Highcharts not defined

Comment: Alright.. Anyother errors you see in console?

Comment: 1.Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined  exporting.js
2. Warning msg :Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. 
3.Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highCharts is not a function in jquery.min.js:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the library you're using has a hard dependency on jQuery, try loading it first

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`

`<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>`

Comment: @AnderiNemes
thanks
i tried that also but it gives me an error :
Highcharts is not defined in  exporting.js

Comment: It works for me - are you sure you're loading them in the order I provided?

Comment: Do you load your scripts async ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan no i am not loading scrpts async.

Comment: What happens is that your highcharts module relies on a variable being declared globally by highcharts.js, which may not be present if the files are  concurrently loading. The only scenarios are either highland.js fails to load altogether or they are being loaded asynchronously. Check your console's network tab and inspect the timings.