# Cannot read property somevalue of undefined in Typescript Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular5

I am facing below issue when using the Angular 5 Services, Can you please help me what is wrong with the below code

I have gone through below questions but didn't help me

1. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689140/typescript-cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-in-null)
2. [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604371/cannot-read-property-addevent-of-undefined)
3. [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155296/getting-javascript-typescript-error-cannot-read-property-items-of-undefined)

I just want to initialize the value in the class and use it in the method

Though I have defined the url value in the class I'm getting error as `Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` for the line `console.log(this.url);`

```
@Injectable()
export class OwnService {

    public accessTokenvalue = '';
    public url = 'https://www.someurl.com/id=';
    constructor(private hp: HelpService) {
    }

    public gethpPhotos() {
        this.hp.login()
            .then(function (response: LoginResponse) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(this.url);

            })
            .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue then I just stop the angular cli listener then start again it solved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to replace `function (response: Response)` with arrow function. Each `function` creates it's scope to which refers `this` inside it. Arrow function will preserve `this`.

```
.then((response: LoginResponse) => {
     console.log(response);
     console.log(this.url);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve by using the context in which the 'url' exists:

```
public gethpPhotos() {
       var that = this; // outer context

        this.hp.login()
            .then(function (response: LoginResponse) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(that.url); // <<<< changed to that.url for the outer context

            })
            .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code this refers to the context of the http request. inorder to access the component variable, Use arrow function

```
this.hp.login()
.then(response: LoginResponse) => {
        this.answerList = response;
         console.log(this.url);
)
```